# Changes are not saved in SQL Server Compact 3.5 database 

Tags: c#, data-binding, sql-server-ce, database-connection

I created a windows application with C# 2010, and I'm using SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5.

I'm also using a `DataSet` to change the DB with a `TabelAdapter`, and a bindingnavigat to add/edit/delete.

The problem is : I can do all these commands during the execution, I can see the rows added and edited in a `DataGridView`, but when I go to server databases solution and verify my data, no event had been done !! no rows added !

Comment: Are you loloking at the correct file - maybe look in your bin/debug folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database may be copied from somewhere/Projectname to somewhere/Projectname/bin/Debug/. Check properties on database file in your project tree. There should be "Copy to Output Directory" property that is set to "always copy". If there is "always copy" - your application is working on database copy.

Read about "Copy to Output Directory" in help.

There is more detailed explanation of that problem: [link to MSDN social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/25a093d2-8520-4727-8c6b-f5c3aefb3c2b)

(question about VB, but it applies to C# too)

Comment: Do I copy my database to bin/debug and change my connection string?
and if so, will there be any problem when I generate my install setup project ?

Comment: Visual Studio will copy that file for you to output directory. In "Debug" configuration it will be bin/Debug, in "Release" configuration - bin/Release. About install setup - it depends on tool which you are using to generate setup/installer executable. Im not sure how your "installer generator" works, i cant help. You may try or wait for another answer.

Comment: One more thing - its good idea, to handle connection string programatically. I dont understand why in Visual Studio connection strings are permanently stored in executable by default.